# TFS > how to lock team queries from being modified?

Tags: team-foundation-server

We have several team queries in TFS that need to be locked down from modifications.  This includes changing the sort order, columns, etc.

How can I lock people out of changing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In TFS 2008 and 2005 you cannot set permissions on individual team queries - only give the ability to control edit access to all team queries in a team project or not (by having them as a Project Administrator).  This might change for TFS 2010 however I'm not sure what the status is on that at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Martin.  I was hoping there was something buried on the command line about this.  Oh well.